# tar: How to remove files after packing but keep directory

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tar

I want tar to pack a complete directory

```
tar cvjf dir.tbz dir
```

But make it delete all files

```
tar cvjf dir.tbz dir --remove-files
```

However this removes ./dir too. So I tried to cd into directory before packing

```
tar cvjf dir.tbz --remove-files -C dir .
```

But that still removes ./dir... what does not make any sense to me, because why should tar delete the working directory itself? Can't I pack a complete directory and remove the files after packing without deleting the whole directory?

I have a process running, that constantly creates files in ./dir and want to pack all files each hour and then remove these that are packed. I could mkdir after tar and delete but that could cause the other process that creates files struggle when it tries to write a new file before mkdir had recreated the directory.

Comment: You still have race issues: what happens if the process creates a file while tar is working? A valid solution would be to use a lock file outside dir, and make both tar and the process lock the file while running. Then, you can use `--remove-files` and `mkdir` before unlocking and there will be no race conditions.

Comment: Alternatively, you could sidestep the problem by `chown`ing `dir` to another user, while still giving the process and tar permissions to read/write it via the group or via ACLs. Then, tar will not be able to delete it. The races in the previous comment still apply.

Comment: The locking wouldn't work, since tar takes significantly longer than the writing process which creates a file each 2s and tar can take longer than that, result when tar locked: I would lose snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
find dir -type f -mmin +1 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'tar rvf dir.tar {} && rm {}'
bzip2 dir.tar && mv dir.tar.bz2 dir-$(date +%F-%T).tbz
```

It's a bit more complicated than your current command, but works and I don't believe it has any race issues (provided a file isn't written to multiple times with gaps longer than a minute).

The `find` command finds all files in `dir` that are at least one minute old (so not currently being written to). This list is then piped to `xargs`, which adds each in turn to the `dir.tar` file.  Once the file has been successfully added to the tar file, the original is removed. Doing it one at a time avoids issues with having too long command lines if you have a large number of files. Finally you can compress and rename the tar file.

Comment: I can accept that solution, however I wonder why you use a seperate bzip2 and then move it and not bzip within tar in one step?

Comment: Because you can't append files to a compressed tar file.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround to this would be the following now:

I write a script that cds into the directory and tars the stuff using ./* then deletes. I was just hoping, that -C would do the same so I could have it in one command line but it doesn't.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/dir
tar cvjf dir.tbz ./* --remove-files
```

Should work.